# How to select a group of vertices in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, vertex-groups

Is it possible to select all faces of one of these groups in edit mode?
[image]

I tried my luck with [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Select_Vertex_Groups) extension, but i wasn't able to figure out how that works. It just says "No Group" when i select a face and hit "Select".

Comment: AFAIK, those are *Objects*, not *Vertex groups*.

Comment: I already had a doubt. Okay, how to I select all faces of an object in edit mode?

Comment: Press `A` to toggle selecting all.

Comment: This toggles all faces of all groups. I need to flip the normals of only one group, but I don't want to select 70k faces by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select (or deselect) the faces of a [*Vertex group*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) by pressing *Select* with the desired vertex group selected in *Properties > Object Data > Vertex groups*:

[image]

To select all the faces of an [*Object*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/types.html#object-types) press <kbd>A</kbd> or *3D view > Header > Select > (De)select all*.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't know it would be that simple. Now everything works :D
Thanks a lot!